# update single row item in listview android

Tags: android

i am developing android chat application like whatsapp/hangout.

what i am doing is, Once message is sent to server, the status for message is "sent". And when i receive acknowledgement for that message, i want to change the status for that message to "Delivered".

How to do that ??

Code before sending to server

```
ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = new ChatMessageModel();
                            chatMessageModel.setId(nextId);
                            chatMessageModel.set_id(null);
                            chatMessageModel.setGroupId(groupID);
                            chatMessageModel.setMessage(message);
                            chatMessageModel.setSenderUserId(user.getUserId());
                            chatMessageModel.setSenderDisplayName("");
                            chatMessageModel.setDateSent(null);
                            chatMessageModel.setMessageType("message");
                            chatMessageModel.setStatus("sent");
                            chatMessageService.saveIndMessage(chatMessageModel);
                            mChatMessageCustomAdapter.add(chatMessageModel);
                            mChatMessageCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After receiving ACK from server, code is

```
chatMessageModel.set_id(msg.getString("_id"));
                        chatMessageModel.setGroupId(msg.getString("groupId"));
                        chatMessageModel.setMessage(msg.getString("message"));
                        chatMessageModel.setSenderUserId(msg.getString("senderUserId"));
                        chatMessageModel.setSenderDisplayName(msg.getString("senderDisplayName"));
```

chatMessageModel.setStatus("Delivered");

****here how do i update status to "delivered"***

Answer (score 0):

Use update method instead of add inside your adapter and update at particular position and then use notifyitemchanged().